# Undefined reference to 'WinMain@16' C error

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse (C programming) and I have come up with this code but every time I build it, I get the error saying, "Undefined Reference to 'WinMain@16'". I have spent over 2 hours trying to solve this problem but I can't figure out my where my error is. Can anyone help?

This is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{
    int input;

    printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    int temp = input;

    while(input<=temp+10)
    {
        printf("%d ",input);
        input++;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you compile or build, files are not automatically saved to disk by Eclipse. But the compiler is using the on-disk files. So maybe you just didn't save the file after you've added the main function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling the right and saved file, you have to make sure you are compiling it with the subsystem target set to console, when you're using the `main` entry point.

You can do this changing the makefile.

If you don't know how to do this, or if you're not using a makefile and don't want to change the compiler's parameters line, you can use this directive:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:console")
```

`WinMain` is normally used for `/subsystem:windows` type of programs, and as you are trying to make a console application, you should use `/subsystem:console` and the `main` entry point.

Again, make sure you are compiling the right file on the disk.

Comment: yeah.. i sorted it out :) i tried both the solutions and they worked perfectly :) thanks for the ideas :))