# "...redeclared as different kind of symbol"?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, syntax-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double integrateF(double low, double high)
{
    double low = 0;
    double high = 20;
    double delta_x=0;
    double x, ans;
    double s = 1/2*exp((-x*x)/2);

    for(x=low;x<=high;x++)
        delta_x = x+delta_x;
    ans = delta_x*s;

    return ans;
}
```

It says that low and high are "redeclared as different type of symbol" and I don't know what that means. Basically, all I'm doing here (READ: *trying*) is integrating from low (which I set to 0) to high (20) to find the Riemann sum. The for loop looks kinda trippy too...I'm so lost.

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double integrateF(double low, double high)
{
    low = 0;
    high = 20;
    double delta_x=0;
    double ans = 0;
    double x;
    double s = 1/2*exp((-x*x)/2);

    for(x=low;x<=high;x++)
    {
        delta_x = x+delta_x;
        ans = ans+(delta_x*s);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

^That still doesn't work, after the braces and all. It says "undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'"...

Comment: Use braces - Otherwise you get caught with you trousers down - this is a good example!

Comment: @CodeBewb:- Make sure you have main() defined. Check my updated answer!

Comment: Just a question, if you are just going to be using variable settings in the function, why are you accepting them as parameters?

Comment: Fix this `1/2`. This is integer division and the result is 0. Use `0.5` directly or `1.0/2` at least.

Comment: You need to have a function named `main` somewhere in your program.

Comment: Or maybe you used the function name as a variable somewhere!

Answer (score 8):

You are redefinign low and high inside the function which clash with those defined in the parameters.

The for loop is doing

```
for(x=low;x<=high;x++)
{
   delta_x = x+delta_x;
}
```

did you mean it to do

```
for(x=low;x<=high;x++)
{
   delta_x = x+delta_x;
   ans = delta_x*s;
}
```

However I think you wanted to do `ans += delta_x*s;`

Answer (score 3):

`low`and `high` are already passed as parameters of your `integrateF` method. But they are redeclared again inside the method. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

low and high are already passed as parameters of your integrateF method and they are redeclared again inside the method..

And x is not assigned a value when it is using for the calculation of s..

---

double x, ans;
double s = 1/2*exp((-x*x)/2);

---

Comment: But in the for loop, x starts from "low"...?

Comment: but calculation of s is outside the loop na?

Comment: double s = 1/2*exp((-x*x)/2); // here value of x is not assigned.. 

for(x=low;x<=high;x++)
{
delta_x = x+delta_x;
ans = ans+(delta_x*s);
}

Comment: How do I do that? I tried setting x as 0 initially but it still doesn't work. I even tried moving the s into the loop.

Comment: when i am trying to find the value of exp(-2), i got zero value.. and exp(2) of 7.38.. please print and check the value of s and ans inside loop

Comment: i call this function and it is compiled .. no error.. but the ans returning is zero..

Comment: How did you do it?
Ok, I did:
    double x;
    double s;

    for(x=low;x<=high;x++)
{
    delta_x = x+delta_x;
    s = 1/2*exp((-x*x)/2);
    ans = ans+(delta_x*s);
    printf("The integral of the function is equal to %f\n", ans);

Comment: It just says "undefined reference to WinMain@16"

Comment: from where you call this function? is it from main() ?

Comment: please check it also     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459912/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-c-error

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by main()? How do I add that to my code? (Sorry...totally clueless)

Comment: check it also..it may help u..    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try like this:-

```
for(x=low;x<=high;x++)
{                          //Use brackets since you are redefining low and high inside the function
delta_x = x+delta_x;
ans = delta_x*s;
}
```

or

```
for(x=low;x<=high;x++)
{                          //Use brackets since you are redefining low and high inside the function
delta_x = x+delta_x;
}
```

**EDIT:-**

> **It says "undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'"**

Make sure you have `main() or WinMain()` defined. Also check that main() is not defined inside of your  namespace

Comment: What do you mean? [Noob here...sorry :( ]

The instructions say to *test* it by writing a main function but I should only submit one that contains only the function intergrateF...

Comment: I didnt get that very clearly. But I think you are missing the main() function since the error which you are getting is because of that!

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can cause this error is by "redefining" your function in a code where that nametag is already used as a variable outside of main function - Like so (psuedo code):

```
double integrateF = 0;

main(){
 // get vars to integrate ...
}

double integrateF(double, double){
  //do integration
}
```

You don't even have to call the function inside of main to have an error trying to compile, instead, the compiler cannot make any sense of: 
`double integrateF = 0 = (double, double) { };`
outside of main function.

Answer (score -1):

when u have declared the data type in the Parameters, you don't have to re-declare them.

instead of

```
double integrateF(double low, double high)
{
    double low = 0;
    double high = 20;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

you should do it like this

```
double integrateF(double low, double high)
{
    low = 0;
    high = 20;
    .
    .
    .
}
```